# Is it OK to use the same input file as output of a piped command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, pipe

Consider something like:

```
cat file | command > file
```

Is this good practice? Could this overwrite the input file as the same time as we are reading it, or is it always read first in memory then piped to second command?

Obviously, I can use temp files as intermediary step, but I'm just wondering..

```
t=$(mktemp)
cat file | command > ${t} && mv ${t} file
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No, it is not ok. All commands in a pipeline execute at the same time, and the shell prepares redirections before executing the commands. So, it is likely that the command will overwrite the file before cat reads it.

You need [sponge(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) from moreutils.

Comment: thanks, moreutils looks very useful! Does the same apply to redirection: `command < file > file` or even process substitution: `command <(cat file) > file` ?

Comment: Yes, it also applies in both cases. Keep in mind that the shell is free to setup the redirections in any order, so you should consider undefined behavior to access the same file twice in a single command or pipeline. Even it works occasionally, it is not guaranteed.

Comment: `brew install sponge` on macOS.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use something like this (not recommended, use explicit temp files in production code):

```
{ rm file && your_command > file; } < file
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only should you NOT write your output to your input, but also you should avoid looping your output back to your input.

When dealing with big files, I tried

```
    cat *allfastq30 > Sample_All_allfastq30
```

and it generated error messages:

```
    cat: Sample_All_allfastq30: input file is output file
```