# Bash script that edits itself

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that can edit itself. The line of code I'm trying to use is:

```
sed "s/$STRING_TO_REPLACE/$NEW_STRING/" < $0 > $0
```

But after running the script I end up with an empty file. Any suggestions?

I am creating a script that has two variables that contain default values. The only problem is, these default values will be different for each of the many stations where it will be used. I would rather none of the people running these stations had to open the script and edit the defaults themselves, so I want to include the ability to change the defaults in the script. One of the requirements I have is that the script must be self contained; no other files are to accompany the script and there are to be no environment variables. This would require the script to be able to edit itself.

Comment: I'm curious, what for, experiment in polymorphic scripting, or do you actually think this will be useful.

Comment: this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055005/bash-is-it-ok-to-use-same-input-file-as-output-of-a-piped-command

Comment: consider haveing 2 scripts.  1 is the controller which creates the other on the fly then executes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do an in-place substitution with sed, use the `-i` switch.

I wouldn't recommend re-writing the currently executing script on the fly. I'm not sure whether it's possible or not, but if it is, it would certainly be interesting (read: difficult) code to maintain :-)

Comment: I understand that it's ugly. I'll have to think of another way to do this.

Comment: He doesn't need to edit a script in mid-execution. He can simply force the script to exit when a certain condition is met, such as true or false boolean, then have a slave node (external script) edit the master node (main script) and change the proper lines as he/she desires.

Comment: FWIW the `-i` switch seems to move the original file and write a new one in its place, so Bash won't pick up the change (at least not in the experiment I just ran). To actually edit a running shell script and have the interpreter respond accordingly, it may be necessary to read the entire script into a variable or temporary file, process it with `sed`, and then send the output of `sed` to `$0` using shell redirection rather than the `-i` option. (This might be system-dependent.)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to read and write to the same stream, this is a bad programming practice and usually results in errors.

This is what you should do:

1. Write to a temp file
2. Delete the original file
3. Rename temp to the original file name

   sed "s/$STRING_TO_REPLACE/$NEW_STRING/" < $0 > temp

   rm $0

   mv temp $1

I haven't done bash scripting in while, so verify that I have the right commands.

Comment: The rm is not needed, it should be "mv temp $0", and I have to perform chmod at the end to make the new file executable. Other than that it works :) I wasn't aware that I could delete the script while it was running.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this is a very bad idea and I can't imagine any use case for it that can't be covered by something not this.

The reason this is happening is because when you do >file, it opens the file in read mode and truncates it to 0 length, and the input has nothing to read. You need to use a temp file. You can see more info [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2BAC8-foo.2BAC8-bar.2BAC8_.3E_file).

Comment: He can simply force the script to exit when a certain condition is met, such as true or false boolean, then have a slave node (external script) edit the master node (main script) and change the proper lines as he/she desires. Or he can even use a config file to save on-the-fly data changes, have the script exit, then re-run with the new config changes. I assume he may be testing small simplex A.I. theories. (i.e. Self-correcting code). Bash is perfectly fine for testing small simplex theories such as this.

Answer (score 1):

> But after running the script I end up with an empty file. Any suggestions?

a somewhat belated response... one possible solution is that your script could contain modifiable settings *after* the script's exit command.

to avoid accidental changes to anything but these settings, it would be a good idea to use an appropriate prefix like so:

```
@SETTINGS
@setting-homepage=http://www.goatse.cx
@setting-dns=4.4.2.2
```

below is an example that modifies two variables: one that specifies the default browser homepage (default: www.goatse.cx, new: www.google.com) and another to change DNS (default: 4.4.2.2, new: 8.8.8.8).

**word of warning**

sed is used to modify the contents of the line number containing the desired setting. if there are errors here, it will *spaz* out and overwrite every line in the script with sed-related madness. one solution could be to have the script write another script that then works to modify the original script. another way could be to include a conditional statement that only executes the sed substitution after confirming that the match exists. or perhaps more simply, matching the desired setting string instead of just the line number.

**EDIT: it seems that attempting to perform string match with sed results in some strange script autophagy. i think you need to specify line numbers that are below the exit command.**

```
#!/bin/bash

# find settings and extract their values
settingDefaultHomepage=$(grep ^@setting-homepage $0 |  sed 's/@setting-homepage=*//')
settingDefaultDNS=$(grep ^@setting-dns $0 |  sed 's/@setting-dns=*//')


echo "Default browser homepage = $settingDefaultHomepage"
echo "Default DNS = $settingDefaultDNS"


# find line number of setting, to be used when modifying the value
settingLineHomepage=$(awk '/^@setting-homepage/ {print FNR}' $0)
settingLineDNS=$(awk '/^@setting-dns/ {print FNR}' $0)

echo "Line of setting for browser homepage = $settingLineHomepage"
echo "Line of setting for DNS = $settingLineDNS"



# modify the settings using line number above
sed -i $settingLineHomepage's/.*/@setting-homepage=www.google.com/' $0
sed -i $settingLineDNS's/.*/@setting-dns=8.8.8.8/' $0



exit


@SETTINGS
@setting-homepage=www.goatse.cx
@setting-dns=4.4.2.2
```

Comment: Belated is an understatement. I earned a degree and had 3 jobs in-between asking this question and your answer :P

Comment: LOL and here i was hoping you were trapped in the same dead-end job.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: As [DwB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453005/dwb) commented above, **separate yours into two codes**: One core script that does what you want, and the other, which modifies, executes, and maybe terminates the first. **This is the first thing** you should do.

Also remember that you should **not** edit a running shell script. Read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6303416/780703) to the question [Edit shell script while it's running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398258/edit-shell-script-while-its-running).

Comment: He doesn't need to edit a script in mid-execution. He can simply force the script to exit when a certain condition is met, such as true or false boolean, then have a slave node (external script) edit the master node (main script) and change the proper lines as he/she desires. I assume he may be testing small simplex A.I. theories. (i.e. Self-correcting code).

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing, and I also recommend, is having a configuration file ($HOME/.myscript.cfg) and having your script detect its presence (and version) and create/update it accordingly. This way the first run can ask questions and subsequent runs can do their job without encumbering the operator with repetitive questions.

Answer (score -1):

Perl handles in place edits. Try this:

```
perl -npi -e "s/$STRING_TO_REPLACE/$NEW_STRING/g" < $0
```

Comment: This won't work because you're giving the file on STDIN so there's no file to in-place modify. Remove the `<` for it to do what you're trying.