# Linux remove text from file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

I want to write a command with removes an item from a file `.todolist` like that:

```
path="$HOME/.todolist"
if [ "$task" == "- " ];
then 
    exit 1
fi 
cat $path | grep -v $1 > $path
```

When I `cat $path | grep -v $1` all works perfect but when I try writing back to the file it leaves the file empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Path `path="$HOME/.todolist"` is wrong. change it like `path="$HOME/todolist"`

Comment: .todolist is a file name

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: Is it ok to use same input file as output of a piped command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055005/bash-is-it-ok-to-use-same-input-file-as-output-of-a-piped-command)

Comment: Besides being ask a gazillion times.. You are clobbing your file, you shouldn't use `path` as a variable name and unless use of `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as that-

```
path="$HOME/.todolist"
grep -v $1 $path | sponge $path
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be simpler:

```
sed -ie "/$1/d" $path
```

That will delete any line in the file containing the value in $1. The -i option tells sed to edit the file in place (not really, but it works as if it did). If $1 contains /s you'll get an error, though, but you can use other delimiters if you need to:

```
sed -ie "\%$1%d" $path
```

Note that with an alternate delimiter you must escape the first one with "\".

Answer (score 0):

```
path="$HOME/.todolist"
if [ "$task" == "- " ];
then 
    exit 1
fi 
a=$1
export a

perl -pi -e 'undef $_ if(/$ENV{a}/)' $path
```